# How to determine if $u$ can be written as a linear combination of $v_1, v_2$ and $v_3$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Determine if $u=4x-9$ can be written as a linear combination of:

$v_1=2x+4,$
$v_2= 3x+2,$
$v_3=5x-4,$

I can't figure out a solution for this excercise, I know how to proceed with vectors, but not with binomials. For every way I try to proceed with a solution for this exercise I get stuck because I get an equation system formed by $3$ variables and $2$ equations.

Comment: linear combination with real coefficients? (then you already got answers) or with **integer** coefficients ? (which would be a more interesting question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First notice that we have three non-zero equations but in a vector space of dimension 2 supposing we are working in $\mathbb{P}_1(\mathbb{R})$.  Thus, one can be formed from a linear combination of the other two.  For example, $-2.75v_1+3.5v_2=v_3$.  Then, think about this as a matrix equations using the first and second equations so we have:

$\begin{pmatrix}2&3\\4&2\\ \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a_1\\a_2 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}4\\-9\\ \end{pmatrix}$

Solving this we get $a_1=-4.375$ and $a_2=4.250$

So therefore, $-4.375v_1+4.250v_2+0v_3=u$

By using the equation we found in the beginning, we can get the expression of $u$ in terms of any two or three of the original three vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: see if you can find $a, b, c$ such that $u=a v_1+bv_2+cv_3$.

Comment: Thanks! But that's what I've been trying to do but cannot seem to suceed. Dont know if the solution is in fact to conclude that the exercise has no solution...

Comment: Put a variable equals to a parameter, you will have $\infty^1$ solutions